# SelectedIndexChanged takes a lot of time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used below code for loading and SelectedIndexChanged of my dropdown list.
When I change value of drop down list, it takes a lot of time until it shows value in the label of my page.

```
Label1.Text = "Review Number:" + newReview + "(for preparing of Rev." + newRev;


protected void ddlProjectDocument_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _DataContext = new EDMSDataContext();

    int newRev;
    int newReview;

    var x = ddlProjectDocument.SelectedValue;

    var MaxRev = (from rev in _DataContext.tblTransmittalls
                  where rev.DocID.ToString() == ddlProjectDocument.SelectedValue
                  select  rev.REV).Max();

    if (MaxRev == null)
    {
        newRev = 0;
    }
    else
    {
         newRev = Convert.ToInt32(MaxRev) + 1;
    }

    var MaxReview = (from rev in _DataContext.tblFiles
                     where (rev.DocId.ToString() == ddlProjectDocument.SelectedValue) &&
                           (rev.Rev.ToString() == MaxRev)
                     select rev.Review).Max();

    if (MaxReview == null)
    {
        newReview = 1;
    }
    else
    {
         newReview = Convert.ToInt32(MaxReview) + 1;
    }

    Label1.Text = "Review Number:" + newReview + "(for preparing of Rev." + newRev;       
}

protected void ddlProjectDocument_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var query = from p in _DataContext.tblDocuments
                orderby p.DocumentNo
                select p;

    int maxs = 0;

    foreach (tblDocument v in query)
    {
        if (v.DocumentNo.Length > maxs)
            maxs = v.DocumentNo.Length;
    }

    foreach (tblDocument vv in query)
    {
        string doctitle = vv.DocumentNo;

        for (int i = vv.DocumentNo.Length; i < maxs ; i++)
        {
             doctitle += "&nbsp;";
        }

        doctitle += "&nbsp;|&nbsp;";
        doctitle += vv.TITLE;

        // Use HtmlDecode to correctly show the spaces
        doctitle = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(doctitle);
        ddlProjectDocument.Items.Add(new ListItem(doctitle, vv.DocId.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me ask you:  is that page has heavy content with lots of viewstate. if not what about this query does DOCID has index on it in Database?

Comment: It's probably because of `rev.DocID.ToString()`. As far as I know you're pulling down the entire table because each record has to be converted to a string. I suggest converting `ddlProjectDocument.SelectedValue` to an `int` so that the comparison can done in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. I've refactored it to look more compact and removed the `.ToString()` from the LINQ queries, avoiding pulling down unwanted data:

```
protected void ddlProjectDocument_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(_DataContext = new EDMSDataContext())
    {
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(ddlProjectDocument.SelectedValue);

        var MaxRev = _DataContext.tblTransmittalls.Where(rev => rev.DocID == x).Max(rev => rev.REV);     
        int newRev = (MaxRev == null) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(MaxRev) + 1;   

        var MaxReview = _DataContext.tblFiles.Where(rev => rev.DocId == x && rev.Rev == MaxRev).Max(rev => rev.Review);               
        int newReview = (MaxReview == null) ? newReview = 1 : Convert.ToInt32(MaxReview) + 1;    

        Label1.Text = "Review Number:" + newReview + "(for preparing of Rev." + newRev;       
    }
}
```

I've changed you query to lambda format and disposed the DataContext as well.

Comment: thanks, better than of before (30 seconds) now it takes 20 seconds, my drop down list has 18000 records, it seems loading of drop down list also has problem because in page loading takes time and at first comes that and other elements comes 6 seconds after.

Comment: after restart of my computer it takes 6 seconds (thank you very much)